# URL finder using re module of python

Tags: python-3.x, url, python-re

```
import re
text = 'https://www.urlencoder.io/learn/#:~:text=A%20URL%20is%20composed%20from,%22%20%2C%20%22~%22%20).'
urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', text)
print("Urls: ", urls)
```

Expected output: Urls:  ['https://www.urlencoder.io/learn/#:~:text=A%20URL%20is%20composed%20from,%22%20%2C%20%22~%22%20).']

Actual output: Urls:  ['https://www.urlencoder.io/learn/']

Comment: The `#` isn't part of the regex, everything else is

Comment: Also, using `-` in a character set has a different meaning altogether. You probably meant to match a `-` in the character set, but `[a-z]` without escaping it means **all letters from the ascii value of a to the ascii value of z**

Comment: And since you also want to match the url highlighting feature **along with** the complicated structure of most urls, it might be best to ditch the multiple *character conditions* altogether in favour of a simple "url starts with http(s?)" approach